# How to add address bar for iOS webView

Tags: ios, swift, webview, address-bar

In my app there is a webView with default website google. I see in some apps on any webpage there is an address bar on top so user can enter new website address any time. How can we do that? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Put your web view inside a `UINavigationView`, then set its `headerView` to be a `UITextField`. Something like this:

```
class WebsiteViewController: UIViewController, UITextFieldDelegate {

  var addressField: UITextField? = nil

  override public func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        addressField = ({
            let field = UITextField()
            field.autocorrectionType = UITextAutocorrectionType.No
            field.delegate = self
            field.addTarget(self, action: "addressChanged:", forControlEvents: .EditingChanged)
            field.addTarget(self, action: "addressEditEnded:", forControlEvents: .EditingDidEnd)
            field.sizeToFit()
            return field
        })()
    }

    override public func viewWillAppear(animated: Bool) {
        super.viewWillAppear(animated)

        self.navigationItem.titleView = addressField
    }

    @IBAction func addressChanged(sender: UITextField) {
        if let newString = addressField?.text where newString != searchString && newString.characters.count != 1 {
            // do any filtering you might want to
        }
    }

    @IBAction func addressEditEnded(sender: UITextField) {
        // trigger the page load
    }
}
```

That should cover the essentials.

Comment: Hi Alex, thanks a lot. I am working on it. One question, the two @IBAction func, addressChanged and address EditEnded, where should I connect within Storyboard? Thanks!

Comment: You don't need to connect them to anything since we're adding them as targets manually when addressField is created. It's just a convention some people follow that any function that's used in the Target/Action pattern is designated as `@IBAction` whether it's actually hooked up using a nib/storyboard or not. Feel free to leave off `@IBAction` if you find that more confusing than helpful.